# Redmine 2 Plugin routes

Tags: plugins, routes, redmine

I create a plugin for redmine 2. How a can use custom url in 'link_to' ?

plugins/my_plugin/config/routes.rb:

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'issue/:issue_id/something/:action/:id', to: 'something#new_some'
end
```

Actually, I see my url in 'rake routes', but when I try to use it on my view, I see 'No route matches' exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define route like this:

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'issue/:issue_id/something/:action/:id', to: 'something#new_some', as: 'fancy_route'
end
```

After that make register this route:

```
project_module :my_plugin do
  permission :fancy_route, { :my_plugin => [:my_plugin] },:public => true
end
```